# Arc Consistency in Java, questions on implementation

Tags: java, consistency, geometric-arc, constraint-satisfaction

So my goal is to write the method that solves a sudoku puzzle, we were given the method stub "public int[][] solve(int[][] board)". We are supposed to use [arc consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency#Arc_consistency) and [domain splitting](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_80.html) to find the solution.

-The way I started doing it was by making a hashMap of points on the board(keys) and their current domains(initialized to 1..9 unless given) -> `HashMap<Point, ArrayList<Integer>> curDomains = new HashMap<Point, ArrayList<Integer>>();` though I'm not sure if this is the best data structure to use.

-My question is how do I represent the arcs and the constraints? I have pseudo code for the algorithm but I don't know how to represent the constraints/arcs in java. What is the best way to represent *C:set of constraints to be satisfied* (which are the valid placements on a sudoku board) as well as my arcs A  < X, c> where X is a Point and c is the constraints.

I thank you in advance for your **helpful** comments.

Comment: Also consider `Map<Point, List<Integer>> curDomains = new HashMap<Point, List<Integer>>()`, which uses the interfaces and hides the implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the best to read for data structure related understanding while working with Arc consistency. Hope this will help you!

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.8824&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=XdqgTqmgDIblrAex-Z3fAg&usg=AFQjCNEKp1FtiYbaea6dvF6u7ppVOk-fFg&sig2=duzyH2nU89MYUskD8Blffw

Above link will give you redirect notice just go to that university website and download PDF.

Good Luck!

Comment: When redirected, the following error is shown:

"No document with DOI "10.1.1.99.8824"
The supplied document identifier does not match
 any document in our repository."

Comment: Ohhh i will fix that once i go back home :( sorry cant really access computer in a candy shop lol

Comment: I get the same error as well, is it only accessible if you create an account on the website?

Comment: No ok, just go to google type "arc consistency example java" and in search result find link of "citeseerx.ist.psu.edu" it will be an pdf :) sorry seems link above link doesnt work directly.

Comment: It's frustrating isn't it, Sorry man! try this...This light work other wise let me know I will delete my answer